# How can I render json: in all controller actions Rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

As per the respond_with/respond_to note in the 4.2 release notes... [Ruby Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#respond-with-class-level-respond-to) and:

> I'd like to take this opportunity to split respond_with/class-level respond_to into an external plugin. I'm generally not a fan of the code that comes out of using this pattern. It encourages model#to_json and it hides the difference between HTML and API responses in ways that convolute the code.

So how about we split this into a gem for 4.2, with the current behavior, but also with an option to get the new behavior as suggested here through a configuration point. - DHH

I have installed ActiveModelSerializer 0.9.3 and I have found out that it still works with:

`render json: @object`

in the controller...

How can I `render json:` by default in Application controller?

Answer (score 3):

You should not need to render any view directly from application controller but from a controller extending ApplicationController.
If you say respond_with is still working in your rails version then you just need to put respond_to :json such as:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json

def my_action
....
respond_with(@variable)
end
end
```

respond_with will automatically render the view in correct format based on the mime type of your request from there.

If it's not working then add gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' to your gem file.

Comment: If I do this for both index and show actions, then the activemodelserialiser affects the index action but not the show.

Comment: Yes, I have to delete the .jbuilder files too.

Comment: Do you want to add the deleting of the jbuilder files to the answer and then I can mark as answered?

Comment: Those files are used to generate the json ?  Sure you can add them :)

Comment: I'm trying to work with ActiveModelSerializer though... This actually doesn't work - only works with jBuilder

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your `routes.rb` files to specify the default format

```
routes.rb

resources :clients, defaults: {format: :json}
```

This will modify the default response format for your entire `clients_controller`